# unzip a file in a compressed folder with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, unzip

Basically, I want to do this because the user is not supposed to choose the extraction target directory. I mean, he just opens the .batch file and the uncompression must be done automatically, but not all the files must be uncompressed in the same directory.
The batch file is compressed in the same folder. He opens the zip file and then opens the zipped batch file

Comment: Seems to some steps closer:  http://superuser.com/questions/371384/extract-all-zips-in-a-directory-incl-subfolders-with-a-bat-file-or-dos-comm ; http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=66630.0;

Answer (score 0):

Not using batch file, but it is possible using [vbscript](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=66630.0) (as mentioned by Juri Ruut) Or [powershell](http://forums.jamssupport.com/Topic72.aspx).

Both the links have a good example.